# Test Class Failing-Logic to process Opportunity data

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

I'm having trouble getting my test class to pass tests. I am Getting:

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00654000008inR8AAI; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, OpportunityTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject Class.OpportunityTriggerHandler.afterUpdate: line 126, column 1 Trigger.OpportunityTrigger: line 5, column 1: []
>   Stack Trace: Class.OpportunityTriggerHandlerTest.send_request_on_stage_change: line 101, column 1

```
public class OpportunityTriggerHandler {

    Final List<Opportunity> newRecords;
    Final Map<Id, Opportunity> newMap;
    Final Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap;

    public OpportunityTriggerHandler(List<Opportunity> newRecords, Map<Id, Opportunity> newMap, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap) {
        this.newRecords = newRecords;
        this.newMap = newMap;
        this.oldMap = oldMap;
    }

    public void afterUpdate() {
        //don't run trigger if the update is done by SS api
        if(UserInfo.getUserName() == 'ssapiuser') 
            return;

        //get the id of all involved accounts
        Set<ID> accountIds = new Set<ID>();
        Set<ID> opportunities = new Set<ID>();

        // Select opps that meet the criteria
        for(Opportunity opp : newMap.values())
        {
            Opportunity original = oldMap.get(opp.Id);

            //ignore opportunities that are already on Scenarios stage
            if(original.StageName == 'Scenarios')
                continue;

            //ignore opportunities at different stages
            if(opp.StageName != 'Scenarios')
                continue;

            accountIds.add(opp.AccountId);
            opportunities.add(opp.Id);
        }

        if(opportunities.size() == 0)
            return;

        List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Lastname, FirstName, Email, Mobilephone, Phone, MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingCountry, MailingPostalCode, MailingStateCode, Description FROM Contact where AccountId in: accountIds];

        List<Opportunity> opportunityDetails = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Lead_Create_Date__c, SSX_Community__r.Name, SSX_Community__r.Builder_name__c, SSX_Community__r.Community_Number__c, SSX_Community__r.Division_ID__c, SSX_Community__r.Region__c,
                                                (SELECT OpportunityId, ContactId, Role FROM OpportunityContactRoles) FROM Opportunity where Id IN: opportunities];

        Map<Id, Contact> opportunityBuyers = new Map<Id, Contact>();
        Map<Id, Contact> opportunityCobuyers = new Map<Id, Contact>();

        for(Opportunity opp: opportunityDetails)
        {

            List<OpportunityContactRole> roles = opp.OpportunityContactRoles;

            for(OpportunityContactRole role: roles)
            {
                Contact roleContact;
                for(Contact contact : contacts)
                {
                    if(contact.Id == role.ContactId)
                        roleContact = contact;
                }

                if(role.Role == 'Buyer')
                    opportunityBuyers.put(role.OpportunityId, roleContact);

                if(role.Role == 'Co-Buyer')
                    opportunityCobuyers.put(role.OpportunityId, roleContact);
            }
        }


        for(Opportunity opp : opportunityDetails)
        {

            if(opp.SSX_Community__r == null)
                continue;

            SSOutboundRequest request = new SSOutboundRequest();

            List<string> oppDetails = new List<string>();
            oppDetails.add('Demo56Txt=' + opp.Id);
            oppDetails.add('Demo55Txt=' + opp.AccountId);

            request.Demos = oppDetails;
            request.VisitDate = String.ValueofGmt(opp.Lead_Create_Date__c);

            Contact buyer = opportunityBuyers.get(opp.Id);
            if(buyer != null)
            {
                request.FirstName = convertNull(buyer.FirstName);
                request.LastName = convertNull(buyer.LastName);
                request.Email = convertNull(buyer.Email);
                request.Address1 = convertNull(buyer.MailingStreet);
                request.Address2 = '';
                request.Country = convertNull(buyer.MailingCountry);
                request.City = convertNull(buyer.MailingCity);
                request.State = convertNull(buyer.MailingStateCode);
                request.Zip = convertNull(buyer.MailingPostalCode);
                request.Phone = convertNull(buyer.Phone);
                request.MobilePhone = convertNull(buyer.MobilePhone);
                request.Comments = convertNull(buyer.Description);
            }

            Contact cobuyer = opportunityCobuyers.get(opp.Id);
            if(cobuyer != null)
            {
                request.CoFirstName = convertNull(cobuyer.FirstName);
                request.CoLastName =  convertNull(cobuyer.LastName);
                request.CoEmail= convertNull(cobuyer.Email);
                request.CoStreetAddress = convertNull(cobuyer.MailingStreet);
                request.CoStreetAddress2= '';
                request.CoCity = convertNull(cobuyer.MailingCity);
                request.CoState = convertNull(cobuyer.MailingStateCode);
                request.CoPostalCode = convertNull(cobuyer.MailingPostalCode);
                request.CoCountry = convertNull(cobuyer.MailingCountry);
                request.CoPhone = convertNull(cobuyer.Phone);
                request.CoMobilePhone = convertNull(cobuyer.MobilePhone);
            }

            request.CommunityName = convertNull(opp.SSX_Community__r.Name);
            request.CommunityNumber = convertNull(opp.SSX_Community__r.Community_Number__c);
            request.MasterCommunity = convertNull(opp.SSX_Community__r.Division_ID__c);
            request.BuilderName = convertNull(opp.SSX_Community__r.Builder_name__c);

            SS_Integration_Setting__mdt tokenSetting = [SELECT Token__c FROM SS_Integration_Setting__mdt WHERE MasterLabel =: opp.SSX_Community__r.Region__c LIMIT 1];

            String requestBody = JSON.serialize(request);

            SSIntegrationService.submitLead(opp.Id, tokenSetting.Token__c, requestBody);
         }
    }

    private String convertNull (String field) {

        String returnField = '';

        if (field != null) {
            returnField = field;
        }

        return returnField;
    }

}
```

---

```
@isTest
public class OpportunityTriggerHandlerTest {

    Opportunity opp;

    @testSetup 
    static void setup() { 

        Account acc = new Account(Name='TestAccount1');
        insert acc;

        Contact buyer = new Contact(FirstName = 'Test', 
                                  LastName = 'Buyer', 
                                  Email = 'testbuyer@email.com',
                                  AccountId = acc.Id, 
                                  Phone = '111-111-1111', 
                                  MobilePhone  = '112-112-1122',
                                  MailingStreet = '123 Main St.',
                                  MailingCity = 'Vancouver',
                                  MailingState = 'British Columbia',
                                  MailingCountry = 'Canada',
                                  MailingPostalCode = 'v3v3v3',
                                  Description = 'this is a test buyer contact');


        insert buyer;

        Contact cobuyer = new Contact(FirstName = 'Test', 
                                  LastName = 'CoBuyer', 
                                  Email = 'testcobuyer@email.com',
                                  AccountId = acc.Id, 
                                  Phone = '222-222-2222', 
                                  MobilePhone  = '221-221-2211',
                                  MailingStreet = '124 Main St.',
                                  MailingCity = 'Vancouver',
                                  MailingState = 'British Columbia',
                                  MailingCountry = 'Canada',
                                  MailingPostalCode = 'v4v4v4',
                                  Description = 'this is a test cobuyer contact');


        insert cobuyer;

        Community__c community1 = new Community__c();
        community1.Name = 'Canmore';
        community1.Community_Number__c = '12345';
        community1.Division_ID__c = 'Master Community1';
        community1.Builder_name__c = 'ABC Co';
        community1.Region__c = 'Calgary';

        insert community1;        

        Community__c community2 = new Community__c();
        community2.Name = 'Cornerbrook';
        community2.Community_Number__c = '12345';
        community2.Division_ID__c = 'Master Community2';
        community2.Builder_name__c = 'ABC Co';
        community2.Region__c = 'Calgary';

        insert community2;  


        Community__c community3 = new Community__c();
        community3.Name = 'Walden';
        community3.Community_Number__c = '12345';
        community3.Division_ID__c = 'Master Community3';
        community3.Builder_name__c = 'ABC Co';
        community3.Region__c = 'Calgary';

        insert community3;  


        Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity(AccountId = acc.Id, Name='oppSend', StageName='Engaged', CloseDate = Date.valueOf('2019-09-07'), 
                                           Region__c = community1.Region__c, Community__c = community1.Name, SSX_Community__c = community1.Id);
        insert opp1;

        Opportunity opp2 = new Opportunity(AccountId = acc.Id, Name ='oppDontSendWrongStatus', StageName='Engaged', CloseDate = Date.valueOf('2019-10-07'), 
                                           Region__c = community2.Region__c, Community__c = community2.Name, SSX_Community__c = community2.Id);
        insert opp2;

        Opportunity opp3 = new Opportunity(AccountId = acc.Id, Name = 'oppDontSendOtherUpdates', StageName='Engaged', CloseDate = Date.valueOf('2019-11-07'), 
                                           Region__c = community3.Region__c, Community__c = community3.Name, SSX_Community__c = community3.Id);
        insert opp3;

    }

    @isTest static void send_request_on_stage_change() {

        HttpMockFactory mock = new HttpMockFactory(200, 'OK', 'success', new Map<String,String>());
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

        Account acc = [Select Id, Name FROM Account Where Name = 'TestAccount1'];
        Community__c community = [Select Id, Name FROM Community__c Where Name = 'Canmore'];

        String oppName = acc.Name + ' - ' + community.Name;
        Opportunity opp =  [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity where Name =: oppName];

        Test.startTest();

        opp.StageName = 'Scenarios';
        update opp;

        Test.stopTest();       

        List<IntegrationLog__c> logs = [SELECT Id FROM IntegrationLog__c WHERE RecordId__c =: opp.Id];

        system.assertEquals(1, logs.size());
    }

    @isTest static void dont_send_request_on_incorrect_status() {

        HttpMockFactory mock = new HttpMockFactory(200, 'OK', 'success', new Map<String,String>());
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

        Account acc = [Select Id, Name FROM Account Where Name = 'TestAccount1'];
        Community__c community = [Select Id, Name FROM Community__c Where Name = 'Walden'];

        String oppName = acc.Name + ' - ' + community.Name;

        Opportunity opp =  [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity where Name =: oppName];

        Test.startTest();

        opp.StageName = 'Contract';
        update opp;

        Test.stopTest();       

        List<IntegrationLog__c> logs = [SELECT Id FROM IntegrationLog__c WHERE RecordId__c =: opp.Id];

        system.assertEquals(0, logs.size());
    }

    @isTest static void send_request_no_buyer() {

        HttpMockFactory mock = new HttpMockFactory(200, 'OK', 'success', new Map<String,String>());
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

        Account acc = [Select Id, Name FROM Account Where Name = 'TestAccount1'];
        Community__c community = [Select Id, Name FROM Community__c Where Name = 'Cornerbrook'];

        String oppName = acc.Name + ' - ' + community.Name;

        Opportunity opp =  [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity where Name =: oppName];

        Contact cobuyer =  [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'CoBuyer'];

        OpportunityContactRole buyerRole1 = new OpportunityContactRole();
        buyerRole1.Role = 'Co-buyer';
        buyerRole1.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
        buyerRole1.isPrimary = true;
        buyerRole1.ContactId = cobuyer.Id;
        insert buyerRole1;

        Test.startTest();

        opp.StageName = 'Scenarios';
        update opp;

        Test.stopTest();       

        List<IntegrationLog__c> logs = [SELECT Id FROM IntegrationLog__c WHERE RecordId__c =: opp.Id];

        system.assertEquals(1, logs.size());
    }

    @isTest static void send_request_no_cobuyer() {

        HttpMockFactory mock = new HttpMockFactory(200, 'OK', 'success', new Map<String,String>());
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

        Account acc = [Select Id, Name FROM Account Where Name = 'TestAccount1'];
        Community__c community = [Select Id, Name FROM Community__c Where Name = 'Cornerbrook'];

        String oppName = acc.Name + ' - ' + community.Name;

        Opportunity opp =  [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity where Name =: oppName];

        Contact cobuyer =  [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'CoBuyer'];

        OpportunityContactRole cobuyerRole1 = new OpportunityContactRole();
        cobuyerRole1.Role = 'Co-buyer';
        cobuyerRole1.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
        cobuyerRole1.isPrimary = true;
        cobuyerRole1.ContactId = cobuyer.Id;
        insert cobuyerRole1;

        Contact buyer =  [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Buyer'];

        OpportunityContactRole buyerRole1 = new OpportunityContactRole();
        buyerRole1.Role = 'Buyer';
        buyerRole1.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
        buyerRole1.isPrimary = true;
        buyerRole1.ContactId = buyer.Id;
        insert buyerRole1;

        Test.startTest();

        opp.StageName = 'Scenarios';
        update opp;

        Test.stopTest();       

        List<IntegrationLog__c> logs = [SELECT Id FROM IntegrationLog__c WHERE RecordId__c =: opp.Id];

        system.assertEquals(1, logs.size());
    }


    @isTest static void dont_resend_request_on_other_updates() {

        HttpMockFactory mock = new HttpMockFactory(200, 'OK', 'success', new Map<String,String>());
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

        Account acc = [Select Id, Name FROM Account Where Name = 'TestAccount1'];
        Community__c community = [Select Id, Name FROM Community__c Where Name = 'Cornerbrook'];

        String oppName = acc.Name + ' - ' + community.Name;

        Opportunity opp =  [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity where Name =: oppName];

        Test.startTest();

        opp.StageName = 'Scenarios';
        update opp;

        opp.Description = 'Opp description 1';
        update opp;

        Test.stopTest();       

        List<IntegrationLog__c> logs = [SELECT Id FROM IntegrationLog__c WHERE RecordId__c =: opp.Id];
        system.assertEquals(1, logs.size()); //even though there's 2 updates, should only be one log entry
    }
}
```

Comment: Please at least indicate which lines are pointed out in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of that error message is this:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject Class.OpportunityTriggerHandler.afterUpdate: line 126, column 1

Which would seem to refer to this line in your trigger handler:

```
SS_Integration_Setting__mdt tokenSetting = [SELECT Token__c FROM SS_Integration_Setting__mdt WHERE MasterLabel =: opp.SSX_Community__r.Region__c LIMIT 1];
```

Storing the result of a query in a single object instance is a bit dangerous because in cases where you have 0 rows or more than 1 row, you'll get an error.

Normally this is an indication that you need to insert some test records, but custom metadata types are automatically available in unit tests (similar to "setup" objects like `User`).

In this case, this is probably an indication that you need to check your test setup to make sure that the value you're setting (which looks like "Calgary" in the `Region__c` field of your `Community__c` records) is one that points to a valid `MasterLabel` value in one of your org's `SS_Integration_Setting__mdt` records.

Comment: `custom metadata types are automatically available in unit tests` - assuming the row(s) have been created in the org. In my experience, best practice is to always mock MDT for test data isolation

Comment: @Derek F. Thank you. The test classes were depending on custom metadata types values to be included in the change set. We had the custom metadata types definitions but not the values.